# How to delete one row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database in that i have below table values.

```
mysql> select * from account_external_ids where external_id like "%rajesh.m%";
+------------+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| account_id | email_address         | password | external_id                                              |
+------------+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|          1 | rajesh.m@company.com | NULL      | gerrit:rajesh.m                                          |
|          1 | rajesh.m@company.com | NULL      | http://160.155.187.158:8095/openidserver/users/rajesh.m  |
|          1 | NULL                 | NULL      | username:rajesh.m                                        |
+------------+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to delete  `1 | rajesh.m@company.com | NULL | http://160.155.187.158:8095/openidserver/users/rajesh.m` row.

I'm worried to run `delete from account_external_ids where account_id in (1);` not sure whether it will delete first row.

Need advise in deletion.

Comment: Do you want to delete row or column ?  ``` 1 | rajesh.m@company.com | NULL | http://160.155.187.158:8095/openidserver/users/rajesh.m``` is a row

Comment: delete from account_external_ids where account_id =1 and external_id=<the url>

Comment: @josephjacobmorris - I need to delete one row `1 | rajesh.m@company.com | NULL | http://160.155.187.158:8095/openidserver/users/rajesh.m`

Comment: what is the unique key/primary key for your table? Use it as a condition in the DELETE statement's where clause

Comment: *I need to delete* What is the criteria which allows to understand that this row must be deleted whereas another rows must be stored? For example, this can be similar to "external_id contains 'http://' substring" or "external_id contains ip:port substring"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to delete a row but not a column. You can delete the row with the following statement：

> delete from account_external_ids where external_id =
> “http://160.155.187.158:8095/openidserver/users/rajesh.m”；